# Differentiate between mouse drag and mouse click/released

Tags: java, swing, javafx-2, javafx-8

**Scenario**. I have a graph on which i can perform panning using right click. This works perfectly. Then I added menus on right click perfectly.

**Problem**. Now right click menus are shown even on mouse release after drag operation completions.

Is there a way to differentiate *mouse release and mouse release after mouse drag* in Java Swing or JavaFX?

Comment: [Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) class should have most of what you need. FYI mouse clicked is different from pressed and released.

Comment: If i am correct, mouse drag operations include=mouse pressed+mouse moved+mouse release. So how to differentiate stand alone mouse release and mouse release after mouse move> Hope i am able to put questions properly

Comment: What i share is an interface see what implementation you want to use !

Comment: now what your target ui framework - swing or fx? The answers would differ (fx has dedicated drag-cycle events)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse events are generated independently of one another.

I assume you panning code works with a combination of mousePressed/mouseMoved.

So you need to add some logic to indicate that you are in "panning mode". So if you have a mousePressed followed by a mouseMoved you set a Boolean variable to indicate "panning" mode.

Then in the mouseReleased code you need to check the variable. If "panning mode" then set "panning mode" off and return. Otherwise you are in "popup mode" so you can display the popup.

Comment: Thanks camickr, I have made a similar code change and now it works perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Since event.isDragDetect() is always true, so I was not able to differentiate events. I created a java class to store a boolean value. This was needed to modify final object state in inner class and was not possible using Boolean wrapper class. Later I am modifying final objects states based on mouse clicked and mouse dragged. I am also checking if mouse release is after drag or without drag as below:-

```
private void addRightClickMenu() {
    final SubMarineBooleanUtilityClass showMenu = new SubMarineBooleanUtilityClass(true);
    final MenuItem graphButton1 = new MenuItem("Save Graph as..");
    graphButton1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            saveGraphAs();
        }
    });

    final MenuItem graphButton2 = new MenuItem("Reset Graph");

    graphButton2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            resetGraph(controlGraph1.getLineChart(), controlGraph2.getLineChart());
        }
    });

    final ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(graphButton1, graphButton2);

    //Mouse Drag operation cycle=Mouse click+Mouse dragged+Mouse release

    getAnchorPaneGraphView().setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton())) {
                showMenu.setValueBoolean(true);
            }
        }
    });

    getAnchorPaneGraphView().setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton()) && showMenu.isValueBoolean()) {
                menu.show(getAnchorPaneGraphView(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
            }
        }
    });

    getAnchorPaneGraphView().setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (MouseButton.SECONDARY.equals(event.getButton())) {
                showMenu.setValueBoolean(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

public class SubMarineBooleanUtilityClass {
boolean valueBoolean=false;

/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public boolean isValueBoolean() {
    return valueBoolean;
}


/** 
 * Constructor passing a boolean values
 * @param value
 */
public SubMarineBooleanUtilityClass(boolean value){
    this.valueBoolean=value;
}

/**set boolean value
 * @param value
 */
public void setValueBoolean(boolean valueBoolean) {
    this.valueBoolean = valueBoolean;
}
```

}